# How to build Julia from source?

Tags: julia

I have a fork (or a feature branch) of the core Julia Language and I want to build the code into an actual language I can use and test out. How do I build Julia from source to test my change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the [JuliaLang repo's README](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia#building-julia):

1. Download the required dependancies from here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/doc/build/build.md#required-build-tools-and-external-libraries
2. Clone the git repo from here: git clone https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia.git (or the link to your fork)
3. Checkout the specific branch or tag you want to use/build by doing `git checkout v1.8.2` for example.
4. Change directory into the folder you cloned down.
5. Then, from in the directory, run the `make` command.

> Note: The build process will fail badly if any of the build directory's parent directories have spaces or other shell meta-characters such as $ or : in their names (this is due to a limitation in GNU make).
> Once it is built, you can run the julia executable after you enter your julia directory and run `./julia`

Then you can run the tests for Julia by typing `make testall` and observing the output. Find out more in the [Getting Started manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/getting-started/).

Comment: I also liked the hint that you can build out-of-tree via `make O=<build-directory> configure` (from https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/doc/src/devdocs/build/build.md)

Comment: Would it be possible to explain how to build Julia with additional packages (e.g. DataFrames.jl, CSV.jl) to avoid constant compilation and latency?